# Notation for the interval between two arbitrary numbers

Tags: notation, real-numbers

Does anyone know of a non-awkward way to notate the interval between two numbers when you don't know which number is larger?

For example when describing the remainder term in Taylor's theorem, one claims the existence of a number $\xi$ that's *between* $a$ (the center of the expansion) and $x$ (where you're evaluating the expansion). It seems wrong to write $[a,x]$ or $[x,a]$ since these numbers could come in either order (or in fact be equal). Some possibilities:

- $[a,b]\cup[b,a]$
- $[\min\{a,b\},\max\{a,b\}]$
- $[\frac{a+b-|a-b|}{2},\frac{a+b+|a-b|}{2}]$

Honestly I think these are all terrible. Does anyone know of anything better?

Comment: I'd be only a little unhappy with $[1,0]$. In this context, it's usual to use $(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon)$, right?

Comment: @PatrickStevens Really? Maybe I'm being pedantic but in my mind $[1,0]=\emptyset$.

Comment: @StanPalasek I agree with Patrick on this for what it's worth - I would make sure to state explicitly somewhere that this is the convention you are adopting, but it seems the least frustrating approach. Another alternative is to define a new symbol - e.g. $I_{a, b}$ is $[a, b]\cup[b, a]$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks, I think if nothing is standard then a new symbol might be the way to go.

Comment: @StanPalasek I agree it's not ideal, but with an explanatory note it should be fine. By the way, my undergrad notes state Taylor-with-Lagrange-remainder as: Let $f: [a,a+h] \to \mathbb{R}$ have its first $n-1$ derivatives continuous on $[a, a+h]$, with $f$ $n$-times differentiable on $(a, a+h)$. Then there is $\theta \in (0,1)$ such that $$f(a+h) = f(a) + \dots + \frac{h^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} f^{(n-1)}(a) + \frac{h^n}{n!} f^{(n)}(a+\theta h)$$

Comment: @PatrickStevens Alright, so I guess that notation is in use. (Although reading this without context, the $[a,a+h]$ might lead me to automatically assume $h\geq0$).

Comment: I suspect $h \geq 0$ is in fact true here. Interchange $a$ with $a-h$ to get the negative case.

Comment: An unambiguous but not common way is $\operatorname{conv}\{a,b\}$ for convex hull. Many authors introduce notation like $I(a,b)$ or $I[a,b]$.

Comment: @user251257 I like the convex hull idea, it's very natural

Comment: Another option similar to $\mathrm{conv}$ is to borrow the notation from geometry and write something like $\overline{ab}$. But in all cases you will want to define it first to be clear.